# How to send Data command to IT_100 Serial Port?

Tags: c#, serial-port, ascii

I have a DSC IT_100 . I want to send data command to invoke alarm. However i couldnt handle it.

```
        SerialPort myPort = new SerialPort("COM6");

        myPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        myPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        myPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        myPort.DataBits = 8;
        myPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

        myPort.Open();
```

I am sending data as HEX. Here is my program

```
var sendData = GetBytes("6541D2CRLF");
myPort.WriteLine(sendData);

private static string GetBytes(string input)
        {
            string result = "";

            char[] values = input.ToCharArray();
            foreach (char letter in values)
            {
                int value = Convert.ToInt32(letter);
                result += String.Format("{0:X}", value);

            }
            return result;
        }
```

In programming sheet it says that :

[image]

Could you please help me how to send this data to COM..

Comment: Don't convert to hex, that's just done in the documentation to know what **bytes** to send.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to follow method:

```
public static byte[] BuildPacket(string Command, string DataBytes)
{
    List<byte> output = new List<byte>();

    // Add command text
    output.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Command));

    // Add data bytes
    output.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DataBytes));

    // Add checksum
    byte chkSum = 0;
    foreach(byte b in output )
    {
        chkSum += b;
    }
    output.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(chkSum.ToString("X")));

    output.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine));

    return output.ToArray();
}
```

To get the bytes you need to send to the port use the method like this:

```
var sendData = BuildPacket("654","3");
myPort.WriteLine(sendData);
```

Having looked at your programming sheet there seems to an error:

1. The data bytes shown is incorrect character 1 is NOT 33 in hex, it is 31. I believe that the data bytes should be 3 in you case. You can play around with this but when I use the value 3 for the data bytes I get the check sum they have calculated when I use 1 I do not.

Please note I don't have a COM port or your device to test this so your results may vary.

I read the manual for the device [here](http://homeseer.com/pdfs/DSC/29007363R003_IT_100_developer_guide.pdf).

Comment: Actually it is not worked. Rep is just for your interest

Comment: @goGud Any idea why it did not work ? What happened ?

Comment: i want to set alarm from application. Ofcourse there is no error, but it seems that i am sending wrong data or buildPacket returns wrong data.. I am not sure.

Comment: Ah I think I see what is wrong let me update my answer.

Comment: @goGud Hey can you try out the new BuildPacket that I have put up here.

Comment: @goGud Any success with the new version ?

Comment: Lol why did someone edit and downvote this post ? Stack overflow is completely broken...

Comment: @Dave3of5 this post has been referenced in SO;Meta - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299837/is-it-okay-to-flag-for-begging-upvote

Answer (score 0):

I have this working. After a night of headscratching.

The key is the checksum calculation. The code below connects to my IT-100 (running on a IP/Serial adapter), and sends it both a "Poll" command and a "Status" command.

The hard part (that took me several hours of trial and error) was the bizzare checksum calculation. The algorithm, from the manual, is really strange:

1. Add all the ASCII Codes together
2. Truncate to 8 bits
3. Create a high and low nibble
4. Convert the values of the nibbles (0x01 -> 0x0F) to the ASCII code for the character.

For example, in step 4 above: 0x01 = '1' = 0x31 = Beyond Stupid

My complete code is below.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace IT100TestDriver
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            var address = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.250");
            System.Net.EndPoint ep = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(address, 1024);
            s.Connect(ep);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(s);

            AsyncCallback callback = null;
            callback = ar =>
            {
                int bytesRead = ns.EndRead(ar);
                string fromIT100 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                Console.Write(fromIT100);
                ns.BeginRead(buffer, 0, 1024, callback, null);
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Connected to: {0}", ep.ToString());
            ns.BeginRead(buffer, 0, 1024, callback, null);

            while (true)
            {
                var ki = Console.ReadKey(true);
                byte[] command = null;                
                switch (ki.KeyChar)
                {
                    case 'p':
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Sending Ping");
                            command = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("000"); // ping
                        }
                        break;
                    case 's':
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Sending Status Request");
                            command = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("001"); // status request
                        }
                        break;
                }

                if (command != null)
                {
                    byte[] crlf = { 0x0D, 0x0A };
                    ns.Write(command, 0, command.Length);
                    byte[] checksum = calculateChecksum(command);
                    ns.Write(checksum, 0, checksum.Length);
                    ns.Write(crlf, 0, crlf.Length);
                }
            }
        }
        private static byte[] calculateChecksum(byte[] dataToSend)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            foreach(byte b in dataToSend)
            {
                sum += b;
            }

            int truncatedto8Bits = sum & 0x000000FF;
            byte upperNibble = (byte)(((byte)(truncatedto8Bits & 0x000000F0)) >> 4);
            byte lowerNibble = (byte) (truncatedto8Bits & 0x0000000F);

            // value is 0x09, need to treat it as '9' and convert to ASCII (0x39)

            byte upperNibbleAsAscii = (byte)nibbleToAscii(upperNibble);
            byte lowerNibbleAsAscii = (byte)nibbleToAscii(lowerNibble);
            return new byte[] { upperNibbleAsAscii, lowerNibbleAsAscii };
        }

        private static char nibbleToAscii(byte b)
        {            
            switch (b)
            {
                case 0x00: return '0';
                case 0x01: return '1';
                case 0x02: return '2';
                case 0x03: return '3';
                case 0x04: return '4';
                case 0x05: return '5';
                case 0x06: return '6';
                case 0x07: return '7';
                case 0x08: return '8';
                case 0x09: return '9';
                case 0x0A: return 'A';
                case 0x0B: return 'B';
                case 0x0C: return 'C';
                case 0x0D: return 'D';
                case 0x0E: return 'E';
                case 0x0F: return 'F';
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Unknown Nibble");
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I should add the that IP/Port combination is from a Planet ICS-100 set to either Telnet or TCP Server mode. This makes the IT-100 available on my network, which is handy. If you're using an actual serial port your code will be slightly different.